# How to save a dictionary where keys are predefined objects, getting errors with pickle and json dump

Tags: json, python-3.x

I get errors when saving this with json or with pickle. Do I need to serialize the object in some way, before I can use it as a key?

The code:

```
import json
class my_node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        
node=my_node(1)
my_dict={node:1}
print(my_dict)

#Generates error
with open('test.json', "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(my_dict, outfile)
```

Output:

```
{<__main__.my_node object at 0x7f8224bbef50>: 1}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-283235668057> in <module>
     10 #Generates error
     11 with open('test.json', "w") as outfile:
---> 12     json.dump(my_dict, outfile)

~/miniconda2/envs/pytorch2/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in dump(obj, fp, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    177     # could accelerate with writelines in some versions of Python, at
    178     # a debuggability cost
--> 179     for chunk in iterable:
    180         fp.write(chunk)
    181 

~/miniconda2/envs/pytorch2/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in _iterencode(o, _current_indent_level)
    429             yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)
    430         elif isinstance(o, dict):
--> 431             yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
    432         else:
    433             if markers is not None:

~/miniconda2/envs/pytorch2/lib/python3.7/json/encoder.py in _iterencode_dict(dct, _current_indent_level)
    374                 continue
    375             else:
--> 376                 raise TypeError(f'keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, '
    377                                 f'not {key.__class__.__name__}')
    378             if first:


TypeError: keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not my_node
```

Comment: You need method, which your non-string key to a string or a format that can be serialized to a string in class my_code

Comment: So my thoughts are right, if I serialize the object to string I can use it as a key. And when loading I need to deserialize the key, get the object and replace the string. Something like pickle.dumps would serialize it?

Comment: Yes, you are thinking in the right direction.
Here the story is more about how the element will look when it is transferred for recording. It is one of variant which you can use

Comment: if I am using node.__repr__() method,, this is encoding just the string "<__main__.my_node at 0x7f6ae1f559d0>" and the same if I try to serialize the node object with ```pickle.dumps(node)``` I get the binary representation of the same string. So I need to actually define a comprehensive string for my object, in a method, maybe overwrite __repr__().

Comment: Problem is my actual object is much more complex than the node object in this example.

Comment: @Mihai.Mehe no, pickle.dumps uses a binary representation, so you would probably have to also do something like base64 encode it as well.

Comment: "I get the binary representation of the same string" no you don't.

Comment: ```pickle.dumps(node)``` gives ```b'\x80\x03c__main__\nmy_node\nq\x00)\x81q\x01}q\x02X\x04\x00\x00\x00nameq\x03K\x01sb.'``` as I said above.

Comment: I am testing every word I write here.

Comment: @Mihai.Mehe that is not the binary representation of `"<__main__.my_node at 0x7f6ae1f559d0>"`, unless I misunderstand what you mean by that. But `pickle.dump` doesn't have anything to do with the `__repr__`.  in any case, I suggest not using pickle, the internal details cna change. You should probably come up with your own format. Then, you can `eval` it to recover it if you must. What is your actual use-case?

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, I am about to solve it. I can post a solution soon. My actual node contains other objects which need to be serialized as well. I cannot put the actual code here as it is not open source. Hopefully, we can contribute with something useful today to the stack.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration, I modified the code as follows:

```
import json
class my_node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__.__repr__())
        
node=my_node(1)
my_dict={node.__repr__():1}
print(my_dict)

#Generates error
with open('test.json', "w") as outfile:
    json.dump(my_dict, outfile)
```

Outputs:

`{'"{\'name\': 1}"': 1}`

Now the loading needs more work, (however this is not included in the current question) Briefly, the loading can be done along the lines of:

```
f = open ('test.json', "r")
data = json.loads(f.read())
f.close()
print(data)
```

Loads the serialized object:

```
{'"{\'name\': 1}"': 1}
```

This needs to be converted back to the node object with something like:

```
json.loads(list(data.keys())[0])
```

Which gives a representation of the node as `"{'name': 1}"` Which then has to [converted](https://howtodoinjava.com/python-json/custom-deserialization/) to the node object that needs to replace the serialize string representation of the node key.

A more complete code looks like this.

```
class my_node(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name=name
        
    def repres(self):
        self.__dict__['__class__']=self.__class__
        self.__dict__['__module__']=self.__module__
        return json.dumps(self.__dict__.__repr__())#json.dumps(self.__dict__.__repr__())
    
    def to_object(d):
        
        #if 'my_node' in str(d['__class__']) and d['__module__'] == '__main__':
        inst = my_node(d['name'])
        print("Inst as", inst)
#         else:
#             inst = d
#             print("String as", inst)
        return inst

    def to_dict(self):
        return {'name':self.name}


node=my_node(1)
json.loads(json.dumps(node, default=my_node.to_dict), object_hook=my_node.to_object)
```